# Looping through all items of the JSON with text index on JsonCPP

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

```
{
    "80550560": {"name":" HAdailton Cesar", "name2": "T-Max"},
    "5987810": {"name": "Adnax", "name2": "Adna Zaza"}
}
```

I have this input and I need to output all the names that comes in the input, but the problem is that i don't have integer organized index, I would have to get the string number and also I don't know what the string text index is going to be.

I would imagine something like this, but I don't know how to get the 'string_text' from JsonCPP

```
res[string_text]["name"];
```

Comment: what type is `res`? If it's a normal `std::map` then just use the normal iterators.

Comment: No it's not, it's "JSON::Value" type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `getMemberNames` to get a list.

I'm pretty sure it is possible to iterate through too, but I have always opted to use `getMemberNames'

Comment: Funny thing is, there is no other way to iterate through without getMembersName. I contacted the JsoNCPP developers just to make sure :D Thanks for your solution

Comment: Thanks. That will save me looking again :)

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [documentation](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html) for the `Json::Value` class, it have iterator capabilities like [`begin`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#c12df0d6980600c5bac908ed0f64856e) and [`end`](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/class_json_1_1_value.html#596da1926b2f2a4056bff2edb713eb0b), so it should be possible to iterate the values like a standard container.

Comment: yes there are those, but the thing is that you can only get integers index because there are no actual iterators in it. you have to use a for loop

Comment: @Grego, please explain "are no actual iterators", they actually have all the iterator semantics one used to have (de-referencing, postfix increment etc.)